# Error C4430 - VS2012

Tags: c++

I am getting the errors C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
C2238: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
on the following line.

```
typedef STD_::reverse_bidirectional_iterator<iterator, DataObj>; reverse_iterator;
```

What do I need to do to get rid of these errors?
This is being done in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

Comment: #define STD_std  It should be from DTL.  This project wasn't made by me so I'm not sure where exactly it's defined.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I'm having the same problem when trying to compile DTL 1.37 with Visual Studio 2013.  (Note: The extra `;` mentioned in the answers below is a red herring - it doesn't actually exist in this header and was a typo by the OP.)

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `;` before `reverse_iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef STD_::reverse_bidirectional_iterator<iterator, DataObj>; reverse_iterator;
                                                               ^
```

That semicolon should be removed